# Filling a DataSet using asynchronous ADO.NET calls throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: async-await, ado.net

I want to be able to fill a DataSet with the results of a query that may return multiple result sets, using the .NET 4.5+ asychronous ADO.NET methods.  The code I am using is below.  When I run the code, I see that the first two tables are populated successfully - the following is output to the console:

```
Table Table1 loaded with 1 row(s)
Table Table2 loaded with 1 row(s)
```

Then before the third table is filled, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid attempt to call NextResultAsync when reader is closed`.

I don't understand this, as the reader is disposed outside the loop that calls NextResultAsync.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and LocalDB @@VERSION is "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 ..." (doesn't use `Asynchronous Processing` keyword in the connection string).

It seems to me that the reader is closed by `DataTable.Load` - but why?  and why on the second loop rather than the first?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
[Test]
public void RunTestQuery()
{
    const string QueryText = @"
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Table3 TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('T1Value')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES ('T2Value')
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES ('T3Value')

SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2
SELECT * FROM @Table3
";
    var dataSet = GetDataSet(QueryText).Result;
    Assert.AreEqual(3, dataSet.Tables.Count);
}

private async Task<DataSet> GetDataSet(string commandText)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Trusted_Connection=True";
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = commandText;
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                do
                {
                    var table = dataSet.Tables.Add();
                    table.Load(reader);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Table {table.TableName} loaded with {table.Rows.Count} row(s)");
                } while (await reader.NextResultAsync());
            }
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? Does it always happen on the third table? What happens when you debug it step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at the `DataTable.Load` method, and the offending code is:

```
...
loadAdapter.FillFromReader(new DataTable[]
{
    this
}, reader, 0, 0);
if (!reader.IsClosed && !reader.NextResult())
{
    reader.Close();
}
...
```

I.e. `DataTable.Load` calls `reader.NextResult` internally so can't be used in a loop that calls `reader.NextResult[Async]`.

So I'll have to write a custom method to populate the `DataTable`, which will probably be a better solution since `DataTable.Load` doesn't use async methods.